# parse model data to JSON object

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I need to convert a list of model objects into a JSON list.

```
<a data-model="@Model.Schools"></a>");
```

The list of schools is parsed to a jquery eventhandler when the above button is pressed (I left some code out here)

Here, I naturally want to read the list of schools to a json list.

```
var items = JSON.stringify(button.data('model'))
var items2 = JSON.parse('"' + button.data('model') + '"')
```

I tried the above, however without any luck, it still yells at me for trying to convert a System.Collections.Generic.List`1.

Also I tried to serialize the object to JSON at the button, i.e. `@HTML.raw(Json.Serialize(Model.Schools)` but it just gives me an empty object in my jQuery...

Therefore, how do I convert a Model object to a json object in jQuery?

Comment: May I Know what exactly you're getting in button.data('model') 
I know Json Object obviously you're getting in that, 
But still I want to see the object, Please update your question with console data for the same, 
If you can.

Comment: it's just a list of objects with standard properties, i.e. string int. The object itself is irrelevant, I just need to get it out of my model and parse it to a json object in my jQuery.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about ASP.net but I can help you with Parsing,

Parsing is not works like that, first you have to make that irrelevant object relevant to json object as a string, then only you can parse any object / string to JSON format..

moreover you can use, search / replace methods for making that object more relevant.

We can work together If you can share, what you got. you can show dumy data but with same format you got in your modal as an example.

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong. If you doubt me, go take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

It is achievable without doing what you suggest - Without all the overhead, that is.

Comment: aaah, you're right as I also told, In .net I don't know much actually I know nothing but MVC,
Sorry for wasting your time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your problem statement correctly, it seems you are pretty much there.

you need to serialise your list into Razor attribute (don't use `@Html.Raw` helper as it will not escape your string and mess with your page):

#### Full .net framework

```cs
<a id="btnModel" data-model="@Json.Encode(Model.Schools)" onclick="process()">TEST</a>
<!-- assuming you have Newtonsoft.Json package installed, the following line should also work-->
<a id="btnModel" data-model="@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Schools)" onclick="process()">TEST</a>
```

and then in your Javascript:

```js
function process() {
    var m = $('#btnModel').data('model');               
    alert(JSON.stringify(m));
}
```

check out this [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GdSLLf) for working example

#### .net core 3

Apparently the built-in serilizer somehow garbles the formatting so it needs proper html encoding. This unfortunately will mean you have to decode it in Javascript. One way to avoid this hassle would be to output your json string into javasctipt block (see second example)

```
<a id="btnModel" data-model="@Html.Encode(Json.Serialize(Model.Schools))" onclick="process()">Method 1 - Lotsa pain</a>
<a id="btnModel1" onclick="process1()">Method 2 - Less back and forth</a>
```

```js
function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}
function process() {
    var a = $('#btnModel').data('model');
    a = JSON.parse(decodeHtml(a));
    alert(JSON.stringify(a));
}
function process1() {
    var a = @Json.Serialize(Model.Schools);
    alert(JSON.stringify(a));
}
```

Comment: This does not work, my version of mvc does not support `@Json.encode`. I did however use `@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Schools)`. This returns some sort of readable data, but just [{ which is wierd.

Comment: intersting, I replaced my call with yours and it still seems to work as expected. What version .net are you targeting?

Comment: I'm targeting .net core 3.1 :-) It's pretty wierd yes. Though it may not make any difference, the property is added with `Html.append()`.. However, all my other properties which are not objects, are successfully fetched in my jQuery - and they are added with html.append too.

Comment: right. I've got sidetracked by your mvc4 tag - I assumed you deal with full framework.

Comment: oh right.. that makes sense. sorry! i edited my question.